# What is the origin of the name "Frankenstein"?

Tags: name-significance, frankenstein, mary-shelley

The name "Frankenstein" is famous enough to have entered popular culture, even if people often get confused about whether it refers to the scientist or the monster. But where did Mary Shelley get this name from? Did it come from a particular real-life person, a local legend from somewhere in Europe, some significant hidden meaning? Surely it's more than just a random German-sounding name?

Answer (score 3):

An easy might-be-true answer is in Wikipedia: from [Burg Frankenstein,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_Castle) a castle in Germany, where your predecessors conjectured Shelley visited and *possibly* drew inspiration from the castle's legends.

This story is not universally believed, however. See the essay ["Frankenstein – the monster’s home?"](http://www.eberstadt-frankenstein.de/content/066_Any_monster_at_home_English_version.pdf) by Michael Mueller for a forceful denial of every insinuation found in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: What is your source for this? Is there anything by Mary Shelley which says she visited the castle?

Comment: The web page in my answer, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_Castle .  It seems there is a long-standing version of this hokey-sounding story.  Just because it's in Wikipedia doesn't automatically mean its false...

Comment: I didn't say it was false. I commented because it's preferable to have your references in your answer, because if the link ever goes down, your answer will lose some of its value.

Comment: @Gallifreyan , I have added another fragile link.  I am flattered that you posit some value to my answer, but am comfortable with  the risk that its value might diminish.

Comment: This is a decent theory (although as @Gall said, your answer would be improved by including the evidence *here* rather than sending the reader elsewhere to find it). Are there any other plausible theories about the origin of the name?